# Trying to get property 'Name' of non-object laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i need some help in my project , i got this error " Trying to get property 'Nom' of non-object " .
this is the code :

Controller :

```
public function rdv($Name,$ID)
{


     $name=doc::find($Name);
     $iden=doc::find($ID);

    return view ('/rendezvous',['go'=>[$name]]) ;

}
```

and this is the view rendezvous :

```
  <title> RDV chez {{$go->Name}}</title>
```

THANK YOU FOR THE HELP ? I NEED TO SHOW THE NAME IN THE TITLE

Comment: What is `doc`? It's an eloquent model? If it is, which is the primary key?

Comment: it's the model yes , primary key is ID

Comment: Try with  `return view ('/rendezvous', [ 'go' => $iden ]);`

Comment: he show me only RDV chez , without the name :(

Comment: The problem is that the $go object is null, thus it has no Name attribute

Comment: So, your `doc` model have an attribute `Name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Retrieving Single Models](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models).

**Not Found Exceptions**

> Sometimes you may wish to throw an exception if a model is not found. This is particularly useful in routes or controllers. The `findOrFail` method will retrieve the first result of the query; however, if no result is found, a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` will be thrown:

So, in the variable `$ID` you will need to have the value of the `id` of an existing model in your database. Then you'll can:

```
public function rdv($Name,$ID)
{
    $model = doc::findOrFail($ID);

    return view ('rendezvous', ['go' => $model]);
}
```

And then in the `rendezvous` view you'll can access to the model properties like `id` and `name`:

```
<small>The model ID is: {{ $go->id }}</small>
<title>RDV chez {{ $go->name }}</title>
```

Comment: Thank you thaat woooork 

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access an array like an object. Instead of `$go->Name` use `$go[0]`. But this is just a workaround.

Actual solution would be to send your variable to your view like so:

```
return view ('/rendezvous',['go'=> ['Name' => $name]]);
```

And then in your view:

```
<title> RDV chez {{$go['Name']}}</title>
```

Comment: this is work thank you but he didin't show me the name , he is only show RDV chez without the name

Comment: ok try `return view ('/rendezvous',['go'=> $iden]);` since $iden will actually have a model since you are trying to find based on ID. Then in your view do the same that you did before i.e. `<title> RDV chez {{$go->Name}}</title>`

Comment: the same problem :(

Comment: hmm, try `dd($iden)` below `$iden = doc::find($ID);` and post here what it contains

Answer (score 1):

Try this out fetching with find() is dealing the the primary key which is most likely the ID

```
public function rdv($Name,$ID)
{
     $name=doc::find($ID);

    return view ('/rendezvous',['go' => $name]);
}
```

and in your view

```
<title> RDV chez {{$go->name}}</title>
```

I hope this helps