# 404 Not found with laravel 6

Tags: laravel, forms, http-status-code-404

i have a problem while passing a variable into the URL , the route exists but still 404 NOT FOUND , 
This is the form :

```
<form action="/rdv_{{$go->ID}}" method="post" role="form" data-aos="fade-up">
       @csrf
     <input placeholder="Email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" />
     <input placeholder="Votre numéro de téléphone " type="text" class="form-control" name="tel" 
      id="subject" /> 
    <div id="buttons"> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Prendre un rendez-vous </button>
    </div> 
</form>
```

And this is the controller :

```
 public function rdv ($ID) {

        $nm=request('email');
        $tel=request('tel');
        $ID=request('{{$go->ID}}');

        $doctor=doc::findOrFail($ID);
        $rdv = new rendezvous() ;
        $rdv->Email=$nm;
        $rdv->Numéro_de_téléphone=$tel;
        $rdv->IDD=$doctor->ID;
        $rdv-> save();
        return redirect('/index') ; 
     }

}
```

and finally this is the route :

```
Route::post('/rdv_{ID}','rendezv@rdv');
```

Comment: Try assigning a name to your route. Something like `Route::post('/rdv/{ID}','rendezv@rdv')->name('rendezv.rdv');` and in your form action use the route helper `<form action="{{ route('rendezv.rdv', $go->ID) }}" method="post">`

Comment: Hello , same problem :(

Comment: Then could be the `doc::findOrFail($ID);`. Are you sure you have a record with the same id it's in the `$ID` variable?

Comment: when i remove findOrfail and change it into : ' doc::find($ID) ; ' , another error appear : 'Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object'

Comment: And yes im sure $ID

Comment: The error you indicate happens with `find`, means that there is no record with that value. I remember that in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61704420/7498116) you accepted the answer that the attributes of the model were lowercase instead of uppercase. So I guess the same thing may be happening here, `$go->ID` is returning a null value, and not the `id` value. Try using lowercase `<form action="{{ route('rendezv.rdv', $go->id) }}" method="post">` or just pass the entire model   `<form action="{{ route('rendezv.rdv', $go) }}" method="post">`

Answer (score 1):

I have two observations:

First, I can see that your form action is "/rdv_{{$go->ID}}". I think it should be `"/rdv/{{$go->ID}}"` instead. Note that I changed the '_' to '/'.

Second, I think you should also change your route to this (Note that I changed the '_' to '/'):

```
Route::post('/rdv/{ID}','rendezv@rdv');
```

Hope that solves the problem.

Regards.