# 404 NOT FOUND EDIT AND UPDATE LARAVEL 6

Tags: php, laravel, edit

while passing variable in URL to edit and update a form it's returning only 404 not found , the tutorials did not help me , so this is my code :

**controller : rendezv.php**

```
 public function editer ($id) {

        $rdv= rendezvous::findOrFail('id');
        return view ('/edit', ['modifier'=>$rdv]);

}

    public function update(Request $request ,$id)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [

            'email' => 'required' ,
            'tel'   => 'required' 
        ]);

        //modifier rendez vous 

        $editer=rendezvous::findOrFail('id');
        $editer->Email = $request->input('email');
        $editer->tel   = $request->input('tel');
        $editer-> save();

        return redirect('/index');
    }
```

**and this this edit.blade.php**

```
<form action="/update/{{$modifier->id}}" method="post" role="form" data-aos="fade-up">
   @csrf
   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH" />
   <input placeholder="{{$modifier->Email}}" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"  data-msg="Please enter your name " />
   <input placeholder="{{$modifier->Numéro_de_téléphone}} " type="text" class="form-control" name="tel" id="subject" data-rule="minlen:8" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 numbers" /> </i>
   <div id="buttons"> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> modifier </button>
   </div> 
   </form>
```

**and finally route :**

```
Route::get('/rendezvous_{ID}', 'doctor@rdv');

Route::post('/rdv','rendezv@rdv');

Route::post('/bienvenu','doctor@authentification')->name('aziz');

Route::get('/edit/{id}','rendezv@editer');
```

need yr help guys , and thank you

Comment: Please provide the error responses

Comment: 404 Not found this is what i got

Comment: Please provide the full route file

Comment: i did it you can check it now

Comment: Are you getting 404 in update? or Both edit and update?

Comment: yees for the both

Comment: Does this answer your question? [404 Not found with laravel 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841553/404-not-found-with-laravel-6)

Comment: no not really :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the route for `update`

```
Route::patch('/update/{id}','rendezv@update');
```

You get `404` for both edit and update for `findOrFail()` method. You are passing `string` `'id'` instead of `$id`.

In `editer` method please replace

```
$rdv= rendezvous::findOrFail('id');
```

with

```
$rdv= rendezvous::findOrFail($id);
```

In `update` method please replace

```
$editer=rendezvous::findOrFail('id');
```

With

```
$editer=rendezvous::findOrFail($id);
```

Furthermore, `findOrFail()` method will return `404` if no data is found with the given `$id`

Comment: yes even i change them it's return 404 not found , i guess the error in $id

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a post route:

```
Route::post('/edit/{id}','rendezv@update');
```

Answer (score 1):

You route `/update/{{$modifier->id}}` doesn't exist, you need to declare it in you router file:

```
Route::post('/update/{id}','rendezv@update');
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

[image]

What you are looking for is a `Route::post('/edit/{id}','rendezv@update');` or `put` or `patch`